# Assigning an integer value to an output row, pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm using kettle in a very basic way. What I want to do is read from csv file, do some kind of transformation in User Defined Java Class step and write output to a text file.

[a picture http://imageshack.com/a/img34/1669/vo18.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img34/1669/vo18.png)

When I run this I essentially get this error:

```
value Integer<binary-string> : There was a data type error: the data type of java.lang.Long object [100] does not correspond to value meta [Integer<binary-string>]
```

This is the line in UDJC step that seems to make the problem (field "value" is of Integer type):

```
get(Fields.Out, "value").setValue(out_row,new Long(100));
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using lazy conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer is: Turn lazy conversion off.