# The data type of java.lang.String object [] does not correspond to value meta [Date]

Tags: python, pandas, pentaho

Using Pentaho with Python Plugin, I have an incoming CSV which has two fields, `Month` and `Year`, that I need to create a `Date` out of. `Month` contains full month names, e.g., "January", "February", etc.

To do this, I create `pandas` script ("create date"), then add `Day` field and set to 1, then get the month numbers from `Month`, then create `date_tw` field and create the datetime from `Year`, `Month`, `Day`.

`create date` outputs all fields, and the new `date_tw` field as `Date` type.

[image]

One of the field outputs from python script:

[image]

`Data Output` creates a table and `date_tw` is of `Date` type.

---

**So far we have:** newly created `date_tw` from python, which is fed to `Data Output`, which has already created the table with `date_tw` also as `Date` type. Both are `Date` types.

Yet I get this error:

> date_tw Date : There was a data type error: the data type of java.lang.String object [06/01/2017] does not correspond to value meta [Date]

It looks like I should [turn off "Lazy Conversion"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661052/assigning-an-integer-value-to-an-output-row-pentaho) at the CSV file input step. This was also done.

**Pandas script in Pentaho:**

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar as cal

df['Day'] = 1
mapping = {v : k for k, v in enumerate(cal.month_name)}
df['Month'] = df['Month'].map(mapping) 
df['date_tw'] = ''
df['date_tw'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']], format='%Y/%m/%d')
df['date_tw'] = df['date_tw'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

result_df = df
```

**Postgresql table field:**

[image]

**Data types match and lazy conversion is off. What am I missing?**

Comment: Not familiar with this tool, but it looks like you declared the type as Date, but with `strftime`, the result is a string. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Pentaho says the output is coming as type `Date` though. You're able to cast the string to `Date` usually in the output. I'm doing it because I want to format to `%m/%d/%Y` and `pd.to_datetime(total_wine[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']], format='%m/%d/%Y')` doesn't  format it as such.

Comment: You can't control the `__repr__`, but they're still datetime objects. When you attempt to "change" the format, you're actually converting datetime -> string. Not sure if that's legitimate or not, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is the goal then to format it using `dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` then convert it back to date using `to_datetime`?

Comment: No, that is not going to change the "format". The format is only what you "see". Under the hood, it is still the very same datetime object that represents the same date. If the external format means so much to you, why not just declare `date_tw` a string?

Comment: Looks like your script creates a String column, instead of Date. I'd suggest you to try following options: A) remove strftime conversion to create values of Date type instead of String (though not sure if python's dates are compatible with pentaho's dates. B) if the previous does not work, then change python's output type from Date to String (if the type is customizable for Python step), then add `Select Values` step to convert Strings to Dates.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho metadata contains the date format for each object of type Date. And the `date_tw` of the `Python script` seams to be in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

You can check the type and format of any field with a right click on the `Python script` and select `Output fields...`. Check if it is dd/mm/yyyy nd not your locale.

If it is not and if the `Python script` does not let you specify the date format, do it with the strftime on the last but one line.